# XSL/XML: HOw to put html tags in an xml doc so they render

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I try replacing the tags like this:

```
<node><br></node> -- >  <node>&lt;br&gt;</node>
```

unfortunately when the xsl parses the xml file i actually get

```
<br>
```

displayed on the page instead of having it displayed as markup.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

HTML isn't XML, although they do look very similar; there's four things that are valid in HTML that you can't do with XML, all of which can be modified to be XML compliant:

- Unclosed tags, as you discovered. Just replace these with a closed version- `<br>` to `<br/>` etc.
- Attributes without values, such as in `<input type="checkbox" checked>`. Just assign them a value with the same name as the attribute, i.e. `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />`.
- Mismatched tags- these are a little trickier. For example, it's legal in HTML to do `<b>A<i>B</b>C</i>`, which would make A bold, C italic, and B both bold and italic. You can make this XML compliant by doing `<b>A<i>B</i></b><i>C</i>` or `<b>A</b><i><b>B</b>C</i>`.
- Most entities. Only `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, `&quot;`, `&apos;` and unicode values (e.g. `&#160;`/`&#xA0;`) are valid entities in XML. You can't use `&nbsp;` or `&oslash;` or anything like that by default. To fix this, you need to include an entity declaration at the top of the sheet, such as `<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">`.

XSLT is incapable of processing an HTML file unless it's also valid XML.

As a rule, I always write HTML to be XML compliant simply because it makes the whole range of XML tools available, and there's really no reason not to.

Replacing `<br>` with `&lt;br&gt;` actually replaces the tag with TEXT that happens to resemble html, not an xml compliant tag.

Comment: The statement that with `method="html"` the output is "always XML-compliant" is not true. Having said that, your answer is otherwise very good.

Comment: Heh, good point. I have to admit, I always just use XML as an output method because I want XML compliant HTML; never noticed it doesn't close tags when you use html before.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert a non well-formed html, this is a possible work-around.
Put your not well-formed html in a comment inside the xml, then extract it from xsl.

example of XML:

```
<Data>
  <!--
  <div>
    not well-formed xml<br>
  </div>
 -->
</Data>
```

example of XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="comment()"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text() | @*">
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
     not well-formed xml<br>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave them as `<br/>` and write the appropriate XSLT transform to map them to the output as-is.

Answer (score 0):

The text you provided:

```
<node><br></node>
```

is not well-formed XML document and is not suited for processing with XSLT 1.0.

In case you have:

```
<node><br/></node>
```

then simply output the `<br/>` element "as-is" -- then it is a valid markup.

**Example**:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="nodes">
  <html>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node">
  <p>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<nodes>
 <node>
 1 <br/>
 2 <br/>
 3 <br/>
 </node>
</nodes>
```

**produces**:

```
<html>
   <p>
      1 <br>
      2 <br>
      3 <br></p>
</html>
```

**and this is displayed by the browser as**:

1 
      2 
      3